# UIView added to ScrollView not fitting full screen with Navigation bar at the top

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

EDIT: Small update to my issue, what i did as a solution for now was obviously just having my scrollview white. This fixes my issue, but my real curiosity was to *why* exactly the content view was doing what i explained below. Also still curious to what common practice formatting is when adding a scroll view to a VC with a navigation bar.

So i am a bit confused with what is going on here. I have a VC with a navigation bar at the top and i need to add a Scroll view to it. So when i did that i stretched it to just below the navigation bar at the top of the screen, then added constraints. *(I also made the ScrollView background red so i could differentiate it from the content view)*

Secondly i added a UIView which i named Content view and i stretched it to the exact same position as the Scroll view. Then added constraints for that as well. (No objects were added yet)

I then ran the app to check how it looked and i noticed that under the navigation bar my there was a big chunk of red, meaning the Scroll view was full screen in the correct position right below the nav bar, but my content view was not.

*A couple things i did to fix this was*

1. I extended the Scroll view all the way to the top of the VC, past the nav bar, but when i ran the app i could see red behind the nav bar, which i figured meant it was not right.
2. I extended just the content view to the top of the VC, but this did not seem right to me either, even though both seemed to fix the problem.

*So my questions are:*

1. When adding views in general to a VC with a nav bar at the top should i be extending those views only to the bottom of the nav bar, or all the way to the top of the VC?
2. I am new to Scroll views as this is my first time dealing with one, am i missing something in this situation? Or doing something wrong?

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try to set 0 spacing to the nearest neighbors for your constrains, it should solve your first issue. Another thing, but I'm not sure that's the problem, but maybe you are seeing the scroll view at the top because your nav bar is transculent.

Comment: I actually thought the same thing, that is actually why i am curious if when using a nav bar and you add a view, should you leave space for the nav bar, or just extend to the top of the VC. For example, in a lot of older tutorials i have watched, when adding a view people would leave a small space for the phones status bar at the top of the screen. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

1) Move the scroll view all the way up and beyond nav bar. 
2) Have the scroll view match the height of its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alok. So just to clarify, i should remove the top and bottom constraints for my content view, then add and Equal Heights constraint from my content view to my scroll view? Did you also have a navigation bar? I ask because i am still trying to find an answer if i should be stopping my views at the bottom of the navigation bar or extending all the way to the top of the VC

Comment: i am extremely sorry. i went through the project again and after playing for sometimes these are what i found i did: (will update the answer).

Comment: one i mentioned earlier was to make child view dynamic. i am really sorry